# Making a notebook effect using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following effect using CSS

[image]

I tried using a table and an empty column at second place to achive double-line effect and then I used left and right borders.But I am getting breaks shown below

[image]

I used `border-collapse:collapse` but it then removes that empty column making the trick fail.So what can I do or any other hack that you can suggest.

EDIT: Here is the code

```
<table>
                                    <tr><td>Name</td><td class="target"></td><td class="target1">Age</td><td>School</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Nav</td><td class="target"></td><td class="target1">22</td><td>Abc</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Nav</td><td class="target"></td><td class="target1">22</td><td>Abc</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Nav</td><td class="target"></td><td class="target1">22</td><td>Abc</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Nav</td><td class="target"></td><td class="target1">22</td><td>Abc</td></tr>
                                </table>
```

The css

```
table td
{
    padding: 14px;
    padding-left: 3px; 
    font-size: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #F4C8C8;
}
.target
{
    border-right: 1px solid #F4C8C8;
}
.target1
{
    border-left: 1px solid #F4C8C8;
}
table tr td
{

}
table
{
    /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
}
```

Comment: *I tried using a table and an empty column at second place* can we see your code?

Comment: I would do it with <span>s set them to display:inline-block and add  the borders

Comment: EDIT:see the code .Sorry for messy-naming as it was a 2-minute noodle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the border-style double?
just add a class "first" to your first column and add this style to it:

```
.first{
    border-right-style:double;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KEw9W/

---

EDIT: here's a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/hC78S/3/
I've removed the empty cells and added this to your "target" code:

```
.target1
{
    border-left: 4px double #F4C8C8;
}
```

As you can see, you need to enlarge the border in order to be able to see the double line. (because 1 pixel won't be able to show 2 lines obviously)

Comment: :Thanks man I didn't know about `border-right-style` seriously

Comment: Glad it helped :D added code to fix your demo to be complete :D